# VSCode: How to make className as the first autocomplete item?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

See the below VSCode Intelisence auto-complete while typing "c", It's always `children` at first. how do I change to make it so that `className` is listed as first?

No matter how many time I chose the `className`, it always suggest `children` again.

[image]

This is on a React JS file. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using `recentlyUsedbyPrefix` option in `editor.suggestSelection`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the IntelliSense suggestions  in VS code by modifying the editor.suggestSelection setting.

1. open user settings
   Open VS Code settings by either pressing Ctrl + ,
   or by selecting "Preferences: Open User Settings" from the Command Palette (Ctrl + Shift + P).
   or from file choose preferences
2. search for editor.suggestSelection and edit it.
3. You'll see the following options in the image

[image]

"recentlyUsed" : You will get the option that you have recently used.

"recentlyUsedByPrefix": You will get the option that you frequently use.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, finally used this method. But its still randomly changes to the other one. I think the recently is per page + per attribute?

Comment: There are two settings, the user settings (globally) and the workspace settings. If you changed the user settings as mentioned in the steps it should work in all projects and files, except if you the workspace settings are set to something else. In this case, it will apply the workspace setting if there are any conflicts. You can find the workspace's settings besides the user's settings in the screenshot.